# How to install Teamspeak 3 client on ubuntu 12.04 lts 32 bit?

Tags: teamspeak

I have been trying to install Teamspeak using the following file but have been unable to do so. I use Ubuntu 12.04 lts 32-bit.

http://files.teamspeak-services.com/releases/3.0.12/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_x86-3.0.12.run

Kindly help with detailed steps since I have started using Ubuntu only yesterday.

Answer (score 4):

Use these commands in a Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

1. `cd ~/Downloads` (assuming saved in Downloads folder, otherwise where you saved it)
2. `chmod u+x ./TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_x86-3.0.12.run`
3. `./TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_x86-3.0.12.run`
4. Follow the instructions

or, you could try this (probably for an older version of Teamspeak, though)

```
sudo apt-get install teamspeak-client
```

Comment: There's no need to add a sudo to the run command. "./TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_x86-3.0.12.run" is good enough.

Comment: @RubenBakker Shouldn't `sudo` be needed to install software? Will it ask for `sudo` itself?

Comment: The .run file creates a directory with all files and executables required to run TS3. Running the installer through sudo forces the user to run TS3 as root; not very ideal. Running the installer without sudo allows the user to run TS3 without root.

Comment: @RubenBakker Thanks for that, edited. What if one wanted to install it to `/opt`, would they just move the created folder there?

Comment: this is what i get when i follow the first set of instructions:
http://postimg.org/image/igsft75dz/

this is the last page of the same:
http://postimg.org/image/75jt4zp6l/


after following the 2nd set of instructions, this is what i get:
http://postimg.org/image/u4aa2n9qr/


all in all, i have still not been able to install teamspeak :(

Comment: @ShivHastawala Just try pressing `q` the get out of the license agreement

Comment: even after pressing Q: http://postimg.org/image/75jt4zp6l/

Comment: @ShivHastawala Are you sure you had the terminal focused? Pressing 'q' worked for me, then I was able to type `yes` to accept the agreement and install it

Comment: what does 'focused' mean?

Comment: @ShivHastawala The window that you are currently using, the one that you are typing into. It's shown by a little white arrow to the right of the icon in the launcher.

Comment: yes, even after it was focused, i did not have the option to type YES/NO.
the above screenshot is what i was seeing ...... :(

Comment: @ShivHastawala You should press the `q` key while in the license agreement, then type `yes`

Comment: What after this? :
http://postimg.org/image/7zn2b3hl7/

How do i run the Teamspeak Client?

Comment: What you did @ShivHastawala? I'm the same last step you are.

Answer (score 1):

For those unfamiliar with Linux:

Do the first three steps in the answer from minerz029.

1. `cd ~/Downloads` (assuming saved in Downloads folder, otherwise where you saved it)
2. `chmod u+x ./TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_x86-3.0.12.run`
3. OR if 64bit version: `chmod u+x ./TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64-3.0.13.1.run`
4. `./TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_x86-3.0.12.run`
5. OR if 64bit version: `./TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64-3.0.13.1.run`
6. Press <kbd>enter</kbd> to view the user agreement
7. Press <kbd>Q</kbd> to leave the user agreement
8. Type `Yes` to create the folder (named `TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_xxxxxx`)
9. Open the folder, Run program called `ts3client_linux_x86` or `ts3client_linux_amd64`

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I have followed step by step in this tutorial, everything is describe, how to install and configure TeamSpeak3 server with MySQL - MariaDB on Debian/Ubuntu.
http://terminal28.com/how-to-install-and-configure-teamspeak3-server-linux-debian-ubuntu/