# TeamSpeak only launches when I run the script through the terminal

Tags: teamspeak

I have just set up my dual boot and I'm still getting used to Ubuntu.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I'm trying to run Teamspeak.

I couldn't get it to work by launching the executable file, nothing happened.

I tried clicking the script. That didn't work.

I tried making so they were allowed to execute as a program with no luck.

The only way to get it to work was manually going through terminal and running the script.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Create a new file name it "Teamspeak3.desktop" and edit the file and add this

```
[Desktop Entry]  
Name=Teamspeak 3 Client   
Exec=/<RouteTo>/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64/ts3client_runscript.sh   
Type=Application  
Icon=/route/to/icon.png  
Version=3
```

Simpler Solution

Save and Try opening it
Source
http://codetunnel.com/how-to-add-teamspeak-3-to-the-unity-launcher-in-ubuntu/

Comment: I get an error saying "There was an error launching the Application"

Comment: did you get the right file paths? sorry have to ask

Comment: Yes. I didn't at first but now i did. The icon showed up but still got the error.

Comment: when you run the script does it run correctly? is it on a root permissions folder?

Answer (score 1):

One nice little app I've used to create Launchers for my desktop is Arronax.

http://www.florian-diesch.de/software/arronax/

But a quick google search for "teamspeak" and "ubuntu" gave multiple hits about how to install.  The following link also brings up a good question is "either" your ubuntu -or- the teamspeak you downloaded 32Bit instead of 64Bit?

If your ubuntu is 64 bit but the app is only 32 bit then you need to install the 32-bit compatibility libraries, you should be able to run 32 bit programs normally by adding:

sudo apt-get install ia32-libs

The folloiwing post also had good info for teamspeak setup:

[How to install Teamspeak 3 client on ubuntu 12.04 lts 32 bit?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/344616/how-to-install-teamspeak-3-client-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-32-bit)

it states:

1) cd ~/Downloads (assuming saved in Downloads folder, otherwise where you saved it)
2) chmod u+x ./TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_x86-3.0.12.run
   OR if 64bit version: 
    chmod u+x ./TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64-3.0.13.1.run
    ./TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_x86-3.0.12.run
    OR if 64bit version: 
    ./TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64-3.0.13.1.run

3) Press enter to view the user agreement
4) Press Q to leave the user agreement
5) Type Yes to create the folder (named TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_xxxxxx)
6) Open the folder, Run program called ts3client_linux_x86 or ts3client_linux_amd64