# How can I install and run Teamspeak 3 on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, teamspeak

my friend and I got a VPS so we could run a teamspeak 3 client on it.
We're pretty new to linux. Basically we did (not sure if this was the exact command):

```
sudo apt-get install-desktop
```

Then we ran some updates.

Then we downloaded the .run from teamspeak then do a command to change the perms and make our .run executable.
Then we run a command to extract that .run into a folder (i forget the commands sorry.)

Now, in our TeamSpeak3 folder we should just have to execute a .sh or a client program. We get the error:

```
failed to execute child process <path> no such file or directory
```

Can anyone help us?

EDIT: We've followed these steps:
[How to install Teamspeak 3 client on ubuntu 12.04 lts 32 bit?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/344616/how-to-install-teamspeak-3-client-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-32-bit/424304#424304)

and AFTER those steps we get the error I mentioned above.

```
failed to execute child process <path> no such file or directory
```

Comment: That first command you mention isn't a valid command - did you maybe run sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop ? If so, that wouldn't be needed for the server version of this program.

Comment: "VPS so we could run a teamspeak 3 client on it." Impossible. A VPS is headless. There is no GUI, no audio, no video. The VPS can run the TS -server- and your own desktop can run the client (or a server) but a VPS will not run a TS client.

Comment: We installed a desktop and a GUI. We don't necessarily need any audio or video from the client - we just need to LOG IN to the TS3 client.

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
cd <path to folder>
sudo chmod +x ./<filename.sh>
./<filename.sh>
```

for example, if the file was located in your downloads and the file is named run, the code would look like:

```
cd /home/kulofae/Downloads
sudo chmod +x ./run.sh  or sudo chmod +x run.sh 
./run.sh or run.sh
```

Comment: Nothing happens after running this. Literally nothing

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with this program, but I would recommend reading through their quick start guide: http://media.teamspeak.com/ts3_literature/TeamSpeak%203%20Server%20Quick%20Start.txt

According to the guide, you should download the tar file that corresponds to your version of Ubuntu (64 bit or 32 bit). Make sure you're installing the **server**. I'm not sure what you downloaded, but there is no file ending in .run in the server archive I see on their website. The file you download from them should be named either:

- teamspeak3-server-linux_x86.tar.gz
- teamspeak3-server-linux_amd64.tar.gz

Once you've downloaded that file, they instruct you to run the following commands:

```
$ tar xzf teamspeak3-server-linux_x86.tar.gz
$ cd teamspeak3-server-linux_x86
$ ./ts3server_minimal_runscript.sh
```

The first command extracts the files from the archive, the second moves into that folder, and the third command is a script that runs the installation.

You shouldn't need to do anything with permissions - the .sh file in that archive is already executable.

You should also make sure you have libstdc++ 6 installed, which this depends on. Run:

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6
```

Which will either install that package or tell you you are already on the newest version available for 12.04.

Comment: I'll make sure libstdc++6 is installed. Please note that in the OP I specifically say TS3 CLIENT. I don't want to install a server. We got a VPS so we could both connect to the client remotely.

Comment: @kulofae - Your clients need a server to connect to. You need a centralized server, which your clients will connect to.

Comment: What I mean is, this software does not support clients speaking directly with other clients. You need the server version on your VPS (the S stands for Server). Reading this may be instructive - http://www.multiplaygameservers.com/help/teamspeak3-guide/

Comment: We intend to communicate with an existing Teamspeak 3 server using the client. We need the client installed on the VPS. I sincerely appreciate your advice.

Comment: What I mean by connect to the client remotely is connect to the VPS remotely to access the TS3 client. This may seem convoluted and you may wonder why we don't just install this on our desktops. It just has to be this way is the simple answer, it cannot be changed and is difficult to explain why.

Comment: If you install the client on your VPS, what you will get is software that will try to access the microphone and speakers on your VPS - which obviously lacks those. I do not think that this will have the result you intend; I think that it will essentially do nothing. If you want install the client, follow these steps: http://askubuntu.com/a/424304/103537 - you will need to navigate to the directory where your .run is saved, change the permissions to allow execution (which you have done), then enter command: `./[filename].run` - no need to extract. Extracting is probably the cause of the error.

Comment: Sorry, but just in case that wasn't clear, replace [filename] with the actual name of the file.

Comment: @kulofae "We need the client installed on the VPS." not going to happen. You need the teamspeak server on the VPS. The teamspeak client is suppose to be installed on your own desktop. Btw: I doubt you can install a desktop on a VPS. A VPS is headless ;)

Comment: @drkokandy I've tried that

Answer (score 0):

First download your package

```
wget dl.4players.de/ts/releases/3.0.13.3/teamspeak3-server_linux_amd64-3.0.13.3.tar.bz2
```

Extract it

```
tar jxf teamspeak3-server_linux_amd64-3.0.13.3.tar.bz2
```

Now change to that extracted directory

```
cd ~/teamspeak3-server_linux_amd64
```

Now you can run the server start script

```
./ts3server_startscript.sh start
```

Hope this helps